# Config squid for Windows with basic authorization, but squid still denied access after I input correct username/password

Tags: configuration, squid

I installed [squid-2.7-stable8 for Windows](http://squid.acmeconsulting.it/Squid27.html), try to let only authorized user can access the internet. But unfortunately after I entered username/password in client browser, squid still return **HTTP 403 Access Denied** error (configure was done and squid was restarted).

What am I missing?

**file `c:\squid\etc\squid.conf`** (use the default one with the following modification)

```
# this is the first uncommented line
include ../etc/squid-acl-cm.conf

#... the default minimum settings

# INSERT YOUR OWN RULE(S) HERE TO ALLOW ACCESS FROM YOUR CLIENTS
include ../etc/squid-http_access-cm.conf

# Here, I disabled/commented localnet
#http_access allow localnet 

# And finally deny all other access to this proxy
http_access deny all
```

**file `c:\squid\etc\squid-acl-cm.conf`**

```
auth_param basic program ../libexec/ncsa_auth.exe ../etc/password.txt
auth_param basic credentialsttl 8 hours
auth_param basic casesensitive off

acl User_Authorized proxy_auth -i REQUIRED
```

**file `c:\squid\etc\squid-http_access-cm.conf`**

```
http_port 8888
error_directory c:/squid/share/errors/Simplify_Chinese
cache_mgr TechSupport

http_access allow User_Authorized
```

**file `c:\squid\etc\password.txt`**

```
liuyan:$apr1$JB1IxUS9$t/2b09Xo5GgV08.MeLArH0
```

**password verify**

```
C:\squid\bin>..\libexec\ncsa_auth.exe ../etc/password.txt
liuyan 123
OK
liuyan  123
ERR Wrong password
liuyan1 123
ERR No such user
```

And, the [Microsoft Network Monitor 3.4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4865) capture result from the client PC

```
  Frame: Number = 6, Captured Frame Length = 744, MediaType = ETHERNET
+ Ethernet: Etype = Internet IP (IPv4),DestinationAddress:[A6-C8-20-00-02-00],SourceAddress:[02-00-02-00-00-00]
+ Ipv4: Src = 192.168.117.138, Dest = 192.168.115.245, Next Protocol = TCP, Packet ID = 3619, Total IP Length = 730
+ Tcp: Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=1784, DstPort=3128, PayloadLen=678, Seq=2725249880 - 2725250558, Ack=2901852307, Win=32768 (scale factor 0x3) = 262144
- Http: Request, GET http://superuser.com/ 
    Command: GET
  + URI: http://superuser.com/
    ProtocolVersion: HTTP/1.1
    Host:  superuser.com
    UserAgent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
    Accept:  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language:  zh-cn,zh;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
    Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate
    ProxyConnection:  keep-alive
    Referer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java
  + Cookie: **I HAVE ATE MY COOKIES**
    HeaderEnd: CRLF


  Frame: Number = 7, Captured Frame Length = 500, MediaType = ETHERNET
+ Ethernet: Etype = Internet IP (IPv4),DestinationAddress:[02-00-02-00-00-00],SourceAddress:[A6-C8-20-00-02-00]
+ Ipv4: Src = 192.168.115.245, Dest = 192.168.117.138, Next Protocol = TCP, Packet ID = 13018, Total IP Length = 486
+ Tcp: Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=3128, DstPort=1784, PayloadLen=434, Seq=2901852307 - 2901852741, Ack=2725250558, Win=64857 (scale factor 0x0) = 64857
- Http: Response, HTTP/1.0, Status: Proxy authentication required, URL: http://superuser.com/ , Using Basic realm="Squid proxy-caching web server" Authentication
    ProtocolVersion: HTTP/1.0
    StatusCode: 407, Proxy authentication required
    Reason: Proxy Authentication Required
    Server:  squid/2.7.STABLE8
    Date:  Sat, 04 Aug 2012 02:45:46 GMT
  + ContentType:  text/html
    ContentLength:  1688
    X-Squid-Error:  ERR_CACHE_ACCESS_DENIED 0
  + ProxyAuthenticate: Basic realm="Squid proxy-caching web server"
    X-Cache:  MISS from fileshare.cmcall.com
    X-Cache-Lookup:  NONE from fileshare.cmcall.com:8888
    Via:  1.0 fileshare.cmcall.com:8888 (squid/2.7.STABLE8)
    Connection:  close
    HeaderEnd: CRLF


  Frame: Number = 19, Captured Frame Length = 789, MediaType = ETHERNET
+ Ethernet: Etype = Internet IP (IPv4),DestinationAddress:[A6-C8-20-00-02-00],SourceAddress:[02-00-02-00-00-00]
+ Ipv4: Src = 192.168.117.138, Dest = 192.168.115.245, Next Protocol = TCP, Packet ID = 3656, Total IP Length = 775
+ Tcp: Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=1786, DstPort=3128, PayloadLen=723, Seq=3339579759 - 3339580482, Ack=3553182034, Win=32768 (scale factor 0x3) = 262144
- Http: Request, GET http://superuser.com/ , Using Basic Authorization
    Command: GET
  + URI: http://superuser.com/
    ProtocolVersion: HTTP/1.1
    Host:  superuser.com
    UserAgent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.2; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
    Accept:  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language:  zh-cn,zh;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
    Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate
    ProxyConnection:  keep-alive
    Referer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java
  + Cookie: **I HAVE ATE MY COOKIES**
  - ProxyAuthorization: Basic
   - Authorization:  Basic bGl1eWFuOjEyMw==
      WhiteSpace:  
    - BasicAuthorization: 
       Scheme: Basic
     + Realm: liuyan:123
    HeaderEnd: CRLF


  Frame: Number = 22, Captured Frame Length = 408, MediaType = ETHERNET
+ Ethernet: Etype = Internet IP (IPv4),DestinationAddress:[02-00-02-00-00-00],SourceAddress:[A6-C8-20-00-02-00]
+ Ipv4: Src = 192.168.115.245, Dest = 192.168.117.138, Next Protocol = TCP, Packet ID = 15424, Total IP Length = 394
+ Tcp: Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=3128, DstPort=1786, PayloadLen=342, Seq=3553182034 - 3553182376, Ack=3339580482, Win=64812 (scale factor 0x0) = 64812
- Http: Response, HTTP/1.0, Status: Forbidden, URL: http://superuser.com/ 
    ProtocolVersion: HTTP/1.0
    StatusCode: 403, Forbidden
    Reason: Forbidden
    Server:  squid/2.7.STABLE8
    Date:  Sat, 04 Aug 2012 02:45:50 GMT
  + ContentType:  text/html
    ContentLength:  1142
    X-Squid-Error:  ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0
    X-Cache:  MISS from fileshare.cmcall.com
    X-Cache-Lookup:  NONE from fileshare.cmcall.com:8888
    Via:  1.0 fileshare.cmcall.com:8888 (squid/2.7.STABLE8)
    Connection:  close
    HeaderEnd: CRLF
```

Comment: "http_access allow User_Authorized" is before "http_access deny all", right?

Comment: yet it is. squidclient also report same http_access order

Comment: remove the -i in the proxy_auth acl, it's not required. Looks like REQUIRED keyword is not written properly or may be there is an unprintable char there. Remove and write it again to be sure.

Comment: @diegows, thanks for the hint. i think it's the `-i` option caused the problem. it turned its following `REQURIED` keyword as a normal username `required`. please consider post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the -i in the proxy_auth acl, it's not required. Looks like REQUIRED keyword is not written properly or may be there is an unprintable char there. Remove and write it again to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone here via searching, one thing that need to be highlighted, which is also pointed out by Diego, is that:

`http_access allow User_Authorized` should be **BEFORE** `http_access deny all`.